# Tooltip Style by TargetType only (not key)

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, tooltip

I want to set a tooltip style for all my tooltips, without having to set Style explicitly on every control. Is it possible?
In the example below, only the last TextBlock uses the style. I would like to do it as in the first TextBlock.

```
<Window x:Class="TooltipResources.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}" x:Key="ToolTipStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" Background="PaleGoldenrod" >
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="7" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="This text has implicit style." Margin="10" ToolTip="This should have PaleGoldenrod background"/>
        <TextBlock Text="This text has implicit style 2." Margin="10">
            <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip>This should have PaleGoldenrod background</ToolTip>
            </TextBlock.ToolTip>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="This text has explicit style" Margin="10">
            <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource ToolTipStyle}">This should have PaleGoldenrod background</ToolTip>
            </TextBlock.ToolTip>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Just don't set `x:Key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove x:Key="ToolTipStyle" and Style="{StaticResource ToolTipStyle}". When you define x:key it doesn't allow style affect to all target controls.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. A bit strange that a Style can not be referenced both implicitly (type) and explicitly (key) me thinks.

Comment: You are welcome. When you don't give key to your style it supposed that it defined to all target types for current window.